# Snowflake Stored procedure with dynamic SQL statement Error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am testing following test sp , Proc is complaining about sql command

`JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in TEST_PROC at ' var sqlCommand`

What i would like to be done in this proc is, Run select on table and prepare alter statements and execute all statements.

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE javascript 
AS
$$
    
            var sqlCommand =  "select ''ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE''|| '' '' || SCHEMA_NAME ||''.'' || TABLE_NAME ||'' ''|| ''REFRESH'' ||'' ''''''|| LOCATION ||''''''''
                               from EXT_TABLE_CONGIG 
                               where TABLE_NAME =''TABLEXYZ'';"

            var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sqlCommand } );
            
            stmt.execute();
            return 'success'
  

$$;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a multi-line string using double quotes in JavaScript. There's also a quote balance issue.

Using backquotes (backticks) allows multi-line strings and use of either single or double quotes without having to double them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE javascript 
AS
$$

var sqlCommand =  `select 'ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE' || ' ' || SCHEMA_NAME || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' ' || 'REFRESH' || '''' || LOCATION || ''''
                               from EXT_TABLE_CONGIG 
                               where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEXYZ';`

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sqlCommand } );

var rs = stmt.execute();

rs.next();

var sql = rs.getColumnValue(1);

stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql });

stmt.execute();

return 'success';

$$;

call test_proc();
```

Comment: Thanks. Now sqlcommand works without a problem.
 Can you suggest a way how can i read output of stmt.execute() and re-execute ?
My first sqlcommand just prepare some dynamic sql statement, I want run the dynamic sql retuned from sqlcommand

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to collect the result of your SQL generator from a result set; assign it to a variable, and run a new statement with the generated SQL. I haven't tested this because I don't have this table, but if it doesn't work let me know I can create the table and test the generated alter statement.

Comment: Its working.
 In case to provide table name as input parameter with single quotes TABLE_NAME = 'Parameter' , is there any special quotes needed ?

Comment: No, but the nice thing about using backquotes is you can then use it to replace any variable including input parameters using JavaScript template literals. If your parameter is PARAMETER1, you can replace it in your string using ${PARAMETER1}

Answer (score 0):

Below example is to demonstrate run dynamic SQL in procedure -
Answer from @Greg addresses multi-line in java script already.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE javascript 
AS
$$
  var sqlCommand =  "select 'alter table '||tname||' add (id number)' from t_name where tname in ('t1','t2','t3')";

  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sqlCommand } );
  
  var v_result = stmt.execute();
  while(v_result.next()) {
  var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: v_result.getColumnValue(1) } );
  stmt1.execute();
  var f_result = v_result.getColumnValue(1);
  };
  return 'success';
$$
;
```

Also [refer](https://%20https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#understanding-the-javascript-api) -

Read through - "Here’s an example that retrieves a ResultSet and iterates through it:"